# HTML5 Canvas animation settling at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on an animation. I was to set true / false to settle the confetti at the bottom of the page up to a certain height. I am not sure how to do this, since I am rather new to JS.

I guess would use some kind of condition with:

```
var confettiSettle = true;

...

if (confettiSettle == true){
    ...
}
```

```js
(function() {
  var canvas;
  var ctx;
  var confettiHandler;
  //canvas dimensions
  var W;
  var H;
  var mp = 150; //max particles
  var particles = [];
  var angle = 0;
  var tiltAngle = 0;
  var confettiActive = true;
  var confettiSettle = true;
  var animationComplete = true;
  var deactivationTimerHandler;
  var reactivationTimerHandler;
  var animationHandler;
  var colorOptions = ["DodgerBlue", "OliveDrab", "Gold", "pink", "SlateBlue", "lightblue", "Violet", "PaleGreen", "SteelBlue", "SandyBrown", "Chocolate", "Crimson"];
  $(window).resize(function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    W = window.innerWidth;
    H = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H;
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stopButton').click(DeactivateConfetti);
    $('#startButton').click(RestartConfetti);
    $('#settleButton').click(SettleConfetti);
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    W = window.innerWidth;
    H = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H;
    InitializeConfetti();
  });

  function InitializeConfetti() {
    var currentColorIndex = 0;
    var colorCount = 0;
    particles = [];
    animationComplete = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
      if (colorCount >= 10) {
        colorCount = 0;
        currentColorIndex++;
        if (currentColorIndex >= colorOptions.length) {
          currentColorIndex = 0;
        }
      }
      colorCount++;
      var particleColor = colorOptions[currentColorIndex];
      particles.push({
        x: Math.random() * W, //x-coordinate
        y: (Math.random() * H) - H, //y-coordinate
        r: randomFromTo(10, 30), //radius
        d: (Math.random() * mp) + 10, //density
        color: particleColor,
        tilt: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10,
        tiltAngleIncremental: (Math.random() * 0.07) + .05,
        tiltAngle: 0
      });
    }
    StartConfetti();
  }

  function drawConfetti(particle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = particle.r / 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = particle.color;
    ctx.moveTo(particle.x + particle.tilt + (particle.r / 4), particle.y);
    ctx.lineTo(particle.x + particle.tilt, particle.y + particle.tilt + (particle.r / 4));
    return ctx.stroke();
  };

  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
      (function(j) {
        results.push(drawConfetti(particles[j]));
      })(i);
    }
    update();

    return results;
  }

  function randomFromTo(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
  }


  function update() {
    var remainingFlakes = 0;
    angle += 0.01;
    tiltAngle += 0.1;
    for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
      if (animationComplete) return;
      var p = particles[i];
      p.tiltAngle += p.tiltAngleIncremental;
      if (!confettiActive && p.y < -15) {
        p.y = H + 100;
      } else {
        p.y += (Math.cos(angle + p.d) + 3 + p.r / 2) / 5;
      }

      p.x += Math.sin(angle);
      p.tilt = (Math.sin(p.tiltAngle - (i / 3))) * 15;
      if (p.y <= H) {
        remainingFlakes++;
      }
      if ((p.x > W + 20 || p.x < -20 || p.y > H) && confettiActive) {
        if (i % 5 > 0 || i % 2 == 0) //66.67% of the flakes
        {
          particles[i] = {
            x: Math.random() * W,
            y: -10,
            r: p.r,
            d: p.d,
            color: p.color,
            tilt: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10,
            tiltAngle: p.tiltAngle,
            tiltAngleIncremental: p.tiltAngleIncremental
          };
        } else {
          if (Math.sin(angle) > 0) {
            //Enter from the left
            particles[i] = {
              x: -5,
              y: Math.random() * H,
              r: p.r,
              d: p.d,
              color: p.color,
              tilt: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10,
              tiltAngleIncremental: p.tiltAngleIncremental
            };
          } else {
            //Enter from the right
            particles[i] = {
              x: W + 5,
              y: Math.random() * H,
              r: p.r,
              d: p.d,
              color: p.color,
              tilt: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10,
              tiltAngleIncremental: p.tiltAngleIncremental
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (remainingFlakes === 0) {
      StopConfetti();
    }
  }

  function StartConfetti() {
    W = window.innerWidth;
    H = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H;
    (function animloop() {
      if (animationComplete) return null;
      animationHandler = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
      return draw();
    })();
  }

  function ClearTimers() {
    clearTimeout(reactivationTimerHandler);
    clearTimeout(animationHandler);
  }

  function DeactivateConfetti() {
    confettiActive = false;
    ClearTimers();
    console.log('deactivate');
  }

  function StopConfetti() {
    animationComplete = true;
    if (ctx == undefined) return;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
  }

  function RestartConfetti() {
    ClearTimers();
    StopConfetti();
    reactivationTimerHandler = setTimeout(function() {
      confettiActive = true;
      animationComplete = false;
      InitializeConfetti();
    }, 100);
  }
  
  function SettleConfetti() {
  
  }

  window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
      return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: instead of `if (confettiSettle == 'true')` better take the boolean variable directly `if (confettiSettle)` or in any case, if you still want to compare (until you get familiar) try to do it against a boolean value, rather than a string `if (confettiSettle == true)` notice the absence of quotation (because it is not a string)

Comment: Ok will do thanks mate, trying to work out how to get the animation to settle at the bottom of the page at the moment and not having much luck lol

Comment: I modified function draw() { ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H - 20); which kind of settles at the bottom but not very nicely..

Comment: Anyone have any ideas, really stuck and cant work it out lol

Comment: Working on it!!

Comment: Oh you super star! life saver! Do let me know how you do it so i can learn from it as well - really appreciate it!!

Comment: Do you want it to drop and once settled you want it to stop once the last confetti has settled?

Comment: Sorry was driving home, wanted it to settle but continue to fall ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what we need to do is that as the particles are falling, we add in a settle condition that if settle flag is set to true. This condition will fall in the `update()` method where the particle dimensions and angles are being readjusted to keep it falling.

Within the settle condition, we check if the particle has reached a specific area at the bottom say about 60 pixel in height from the bottom. If it has then we skip it's adjustments to keep it at that same spot.

Here is the sample: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/vyOvxL
(Check comments related to settle variables and methods in the code for understanding)

Click the settle button on the top left to make the confetti to drop and click the start button to start it again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks mate, will have a look first thing in the morning in detail. I just had a quick peak and works great but ill have a play as want it to continue falling... think it would be much effort for me to do this or will the bottom just constantly get bigger and bigger? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I have made changes to the code to have it keep going continuously and settling as well when settle is clicked. Please check the codepen again when ready.

Comment: Thanks a million mate, top stuff!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be sitting fully at the bottom of the page, has a gap from the bottom of the window and the settling... also if i change to 150 particles the settling effect disappears rather quickly... any ideas?

Comment: You can adjust the bottom with the canvas.height statements. if you look in the code you will find 2-3 places with the "canvas.height = H - 60;" adjust that - 60 or remove it to see where you would like to fit it. On the 150 particles. what is happening here is that we have a fix number of particles going on. In order to settle them at bottom we need to stop a few of them at bottom at random to give the effect that they are settling down there. Now to keep the confetti dropping we are resetting them back after some time at bottom to drop again. So the settle effect needs a large max particle.

Comment: Of course if you have less particle density then the particles collectively will be less to cover the bottom based on screen size so that is why. To keep the effect that particles are dropping in on the bottom and the bottom settled particle colors are changing randomly. We needed to do this. I recommend that if you want to keep the particle at bottom then a minimum of 1000 max particles is needed. Then the falling particles will be 500 and the bottom settled particles will be 500 as well.

Comment: I tried adjusting but doesnt seem to be doing much to get rid of that gap on the bottom... cant really have that much confetti as its going over a website... is there no way of holding them in the bottom for a little longer maybe?

Comment: So have worked out a little way to do this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNXWmN?editors=0010#0 - just struggling getting it to sit perfectly to the bottom of the window.